# Login failed for user '.' Error trying to connect to a local SQL Server database using Nestjs

Tags: sql-server, nestjs

I've been trying to connect to a local SQL Server database using NestJs, but I keep getting this error - I don't understand it:

[image]

This is my configuration in `app.module.ts`:

```
@Module({
imports: [
ConfigModule.forRoot(),
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mssql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 1433,
  username: 'user',
  password: 'paswrd',
  database: 'db',
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: true,
  ssl: true,
  extra: {
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    Encrypt: true,
    IntegratedSecurity: false,
  },
}),
],
 })
```

but I keep getting this error.

As a secondary option, I tried connecting to a cloud based SQL Server on Amazon AWS using RDS, with this configuration:

```
@Module({
imports: [
ConfigModule.forRoot(),
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mssql',
  host: 'url.rds.amazonaws.com',
  port: 1433,
  username: 'user',
  password: 'paswrd',
  database: 'db',
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: true,
  ssl: true,
  extra: {
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    Encrypt: true,
    IntegratedSecurity: false,
  },
}),

],
})
```

And it works fine, but my main goal is to connect to a local SQL Server database not a cloud, so I'm wondering what do I need to fix so I can connect to a local database.

Comment: Check the SQL Server's log for the actual authentication error. if you don't understand that error, [edit] your question to include it. Though, note, your application shouldn't be using the `sa` account but a `LOGIN` (and mapped `USER`s) with the minimum permissions required to perform its tasks.

Comment: thank you, i edited the question. The Sa account is a login I created specifically for the connection from nestjs to the sql server DB. I don't have much knowledge about mapped users. but i gave permissions to the user "sa" so it can edit and everything on a specific db

Comment: So what was the error in the logs? You haven't added that.

Comment: that's the only error im getting in the terminal, so i don't have any other logs

Comment: SQL Server has an `ERRORLOG` file that will contain related information. You should locate it and check for authentication error messages.

Comment: We need the error from the SQL Server's logs, @alexschobel . Authentication errors returned to the application, from SQL Server, are intentionally vague. The full reason will be in SQL Server's logs. What that error could be could be many, such as: Incorrect Password, Invalid Login Name, Account Disabled, No mapped user in the database, misbehaving/poorly written Server Trigger, etc. We need to know which that is before we can give answers.

Comment: Yes, thank you guys very much for the fast response. im fairly new to SQL server and found what was the error, i was trying to connect to a db that did not exist in the sql server. I was assuming like in Amazon RDS if theres no DB with that name it will be created automatically. Thanks for the fast response.